# Parse dynamic column csv into one column

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, csv, ssis

I hope this makes sense, but I need some help. I receive a CSV file from a customer of ours and they don't send us a standard format file. For the most part, the file contains 1 column with up to a million rows, but sometimes they will send us multiple columns with a million or so rows in each column. My guess is they are using Excel and saving as a CSV.

My question is how do I clean the file so we don't have to manually change it to be one column? Right now I do a `SqlBulkCopy` with a `DataTable`. There are no header records for this either.

I'm open to using SSIS programatically or just doing the logic within tsql if needed, but would prefer not to. I would prefer to do it within my c# application. A coworker suggested importing into an import holding table and use unions to get one column and then insert into the table that is used for other logic. Please help?!?

**EDIT:**
I figured an example would be useful here so here is my attempt:

The file comes like this:
aa, bb, cc, dd

I want it to look like this:
aa
bb
cc
dd

***Note:*** The columns will be a fixed width, but the number of columns are dynamic.

**EDIT #2:** I ended up doing a different route for this, mainly because of time restraint. What I did was I created an import temporary table that has 25 columns. I used `SqlBulkCopy` to map the columns for this. The column mappings will depend on the number of columns in the `DataTable` and I just use a `foreach` for this.

Then I call a stored procedure to "process" the records by doing a `UNION ALL` for each column and importing into the final table. This also helped with problems with sometimes having a header record and sometimes there would be blanks in a column because it wasn't as long as the previous ones. Since there is a unique constraint on the field in production, there can't be multiple empty records.

Not elegant, but I got it to work.

Comment: To fix this manually, do you cut all of the values in the 2nd column and paste them at the bottom of the 1st column?

Comment: That's an option, but the first time this happened we made separate files and allowed multi-select and just used a `foreach` loop to go through everything.

Comment: Yes, please explain what should occur when there is more than one column. Do you, as @David asks, add it to the end, do you concatenate A1 and B1 for your output or do you just ignore column B?

Comment: The first time we just opened the file in excel as a csv and created a separate file for each column. If we wanted to, we could concatenate in something like notepad ++ or something, but this gets excessive when you have around 20 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Per your request, here is a more general solution. Replace the OLEDB source in my previous solution with a flat file. Then follow the steps depicted in the diagram.

Comment: I did try this after I implemented my solution and I was able to get yours to work. Thank you very much for this!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library like http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/03/24/opensource-csv-reader-on-nuget.aspx where you read data into an IEnumerable. Next use the Linq Select Operator to return field.

```
var resultField1 = reader.Select(row => row.field1);

var resultField2 = reader.Select(row => row.field2);


var combined = resultField1.Concat(resultField2);

combined.ToList().ForEach(r => DataTableToUpload.NewRow({r});
```

With the combined data you can add the dq=ata easily to a datatable.

Comment: would I just loop through somehow so it is dynamic in the number of colums it has?

Comment: Yes. The combined type is an IEnumberable<String> which can be convert into a List<String> and even into a datarow.  I have edited the example to be a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use asynchronous script component. A sample is here. You can make it smart to detect the number of columns and accordingly add those many rows. Practice with it, and if you need help let us know.
[image]

Another way to do it would be to put the data in a temp table and then union the two columns. Again, if you can figure out the number of columns, you can assemble this sql in a script task, and save that sql in a variable.

```
SELECT f1 AS OneColumn FROM [dbo].[TempTable]
UNION ALL
SELECT f2 AS OneColumn  FROM [dbo].[TempTable]
```

Comment: How would this work if I had a different number of columns each time?

Comment: See a the attached image below.I have tried to depict every step so that you easily reproduce the solution. This would work for any number of columns.